# Drools, KIEBASE serialisation

Tags: java, android, serialization, drools, kie

I'm working with drools 6.0.1.Final using maven to create an android app.

To reduce the workload of the mobile i've decided to compile the rules on my destop/server
and then package the compiled rules in the mobile app.
My problem is that i'm unable to serialize the KieBase without hard writting links to the current CLASSPATH.

here is my generating test code :

```
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();


        File rule = new File(getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResource("HelloWorld.drl").getPath());
        kfs.write( "src/main/resources/HelloWorld.drl",
                       ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource( rule.toURI().toURL().openStream() ) );

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
        Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();

        if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
            for (Message message : results.getMessages()) {
                log.error( message.getText() );
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
        }

        KieContainer kieContainer =
            ks.newKieContainer( ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );

        // CEP - get the KIE related configuration container and set the EventProcessing (from default cloud) to Stream
        KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
        config.setOption( EventProcessingOption.STREAM );
        KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase( config );
        File compiledRuleFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResource("compiledRules").getPath());

        log.debug(compiledRuleFile.getCanonicalPath());

        //----- Serialization to file "compiledRuleFile" --------------
        Serialization.serialize(kieBase, compiledRuleFile);

        //----- Deserialization to another object on another computer --------------
        kieBase = Serialization.deserialize(KieBase.class, compiledRuleFile);

        KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

then the serializer :

```
public static <T> void serialize(T o, File outputFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            outputFile));
    out.writeObject(o);
    out.close();
}

public static <T> T deserialize(Class<T> klass, File inputFile)
        throws StreamCorruptedException, FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    T t = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            inputFile));
    t = klass.cast(in.readObject());
    in.close();
    return t;
}
```

to get the serialized file "compiledRuleFile" on pastebin:

```html
<iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Lx3cbcaS" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

the problematic section of the output file:

```
     \sources\sandbox\trunk\gs-maven-android-master\initial\target\test-classes;G:\sources\sandbox\trunk\gs-maven-android-master\initial\target\classes;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\4.1.1.4\android-4.1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\khronos\opengl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.14.8\lombok-1.14.8.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\1.7.0\assertj-core-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-compiler\6.0.1.Final\drools-compiler-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-core\6.0.1.Final\drools-core-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-internal\6.0.1.Final\kie-internal-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.5\antlr-runtime-3.5.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\3.7.2\ecj-3.7.2.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.3\xstream-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.5.0\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.2\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.2\logback-core-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-internal-android\6.0.1.Final\kie-internal-android-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\kie\kie-api\6.0.1.Final\kie-api-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.2\slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-core-android\6.0.1.Final\drools-core-android-6.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\com\android\dex\1.7\dex-1.7.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\android\android\4.4.2_r3\android-4.4.2_r3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.1.8.Final\mvel2-2.1.8.Final.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\com\google\openbeans\1.0\openbeans-1.0.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-android\1.7.10\slf4j-android-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.1\junit-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.12\log4j-1.2.12.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\logkit\logkit\1.0.1\logkit-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\avalon-framework\avalon-framework\4.1.3\avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.3\servlet-api-2.3.jar;C:\Users\AccountName\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.2\junit-3.8.2.jar;G:\sources\sandbox\trunk\gs-maven-android-master\initial\bin\classes;/G:/eclipse - juno/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/205/0/.cp/;/G:/eclipse - juno/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/204/0/.cp/t java.vm.specification.versiont 1.8t sun.arch.data.modelt 64t   java.homet G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jret sun.java.commandt g.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 57613 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames org.hello.SHouldDoSmtht java.specification.vendort Oracle Corporationt user.languaget frt awt.toolkitt sun.awt.windows.WToolkitt java.vm.infot mixed modet java.versiont 1.8.0_25t java.ext.dirst 6G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\extt sun.boot.class.pathtG:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;G:\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\classest java.vendort Oracle Corporationt file.separatort \t java.vendor.url.bugt #http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/t sun.cpu.endiant littlet sun.io.unicode.encodingt
```

how could i get a "compiledRuleFile" that can be deserialized everywhere ?

try to run the createrule.java test from the github repo :
https://github.com/cyrillemortier/drools-serialize
open the file prompted in the console output.

Thank's
Cyrille

Comment: This seems to be two questions. (1) You serialize a KieBase using the standard approach, according to Java lore. I don't see what the classpath has to do with that: you define the path for a simple file, can be anywhere. (2) What do you mean by "generic kiebase? I've never heard of it.

Comment: (1) the serialization/deserialization is ok in my test, my problem is that i serialise my rules somewhere then i transfert the serialized rules to an other computer (here a mobile android phone) then i deserialize my rules and the issue happen at the deserialization time because of the classpath informations included in my serialized rule file. (2) wrong word i've edited my question

Comment: A classpath instructs Java compilers and loaders to look into a set of directories where to find certain packages and classes, and these are searched *relative* to these directories. Most certainly you'll need lots of Drools classes on the target system, but there's no need to have a "hard written link to the current classpath" (and please explain what you mean by that.) I think that you misinterpret some error message (please add it to your Q).

Comment: in other words i want to pre-compile my drl files an then execute those rules in an android app. that's why i'm trying to find a way to serialise/compile the rules on my destop.

Comment: Quite so, that's what I've understood.

Comment: Do you see what's my point with the "hard linked CLASSPATH" ?

Comment: @laune please look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458536/drools-6-1-0-final-setting-for-kiemodulerepo-purge-behavior